# Flatten Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) Schema in Python

Tags: python, csv, relational-database, transformation, entity-attribute-value

I've got a csv file in something of an entity-attribute-value format (*i.e.*, my `event_id` is non-unique and repeats *k* times for the *k* associated attributes):

```
    event_id, attribute_id, value
    1, 1, a
    1, 2, b
    1, 3, c
    2, 1, a
    2, 2, b
    2, 3, c
    2, 4, d
```

Are there any handy tricks to transform a variable number of attributes (*i.e.*, rows) into columns? The key here is that the output ought to be an *m x n* table of structured data, where *m = max(k)*; filling in missing attributes with `NULL` would be optimal:

```
    event_id, 1, 2, 3, 4
    1, a, b, c, null
    2, a, b, c, d
```

My plan was to (1) convert the csv to a JSON object that looks like this:

```
    data = [{'value': 'a', 'id': '1', 'event_id': '1', 'attribute_id': '1'},
     {'value': 'b', 'id': '2', 'event_id': '1', 'attribute_id': '2'},
     {'value': 'a', 'id': '3', 'event_id': '2', 'attribute_id': '1'},
     {'value': 'b', 'id': '4', 'event_id': '2', 'attribute_id': '2'},
     {'value': 'c', 'id': '5', 'event_id': '2', 'attribute_id': '3'},
     {'value': 'd', 'id': '6', 'event_id': '2', 'attribute_id': '4'}]
```

(2) extract unique event ids:

```
    events = set()
    for item in data:
        events.add(item['event_id'])
```

(3) create a list of lists, where each inner list is a list the of attributes for the corresponding parent event.

```
    attributes = [[k['value'] for k in j] for i, j in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['event_id'])]
```

(4) create a dictionary that brings events and attributes together:

```
    event_dict = dict(zip(events, attributes))
```

which looks like this:

```
    {'1': ['a', 'b'], '2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
```

I'm not sure how to get all inner lists to be the same length with `NULL` values populated where necessary. It seems like something that needs to be done in step (3). Also, creating *n* lists full of *m* `NULL` values had crossed my mind, then iterate through each list and populate the value using `attribute_id` as the list location; but that seems janky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic idea seems right, though I would implement it as follows:

```
import itertools
import csv

events = {}  # we're going to keep track of the events we read in
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    for event, _att, val in csv.reader(infile):
        if event not in events:
            events[event] = []
        events[int(event)].append(val)  # track all the values for this event

maxAtts = max(len(v) for _k,v in events.items())  # the maximum number of attributes for any event
with open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile):
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(["event_id"] + list(range(1, maxAtts+1)))  # write out the header row
    for k in sorted(events):  # let's look at the events in sorted order
        writer.writerow([k] + events[k] + ['null']*(maxAtts-len(events[k])))  # write out the event id, all the values for that event, and pad with "null" for any attributes without values
```